# Tramp can not connect to remote server

Tags: emacs, ssh, tramp

I have upgraded my emacs and updated some el-get packages including tramp (my system is a bit old, and I could not upgrade some emacs packages), and now I can not use tramp to connect to a remote server:

```
Tramp: Opening connection for server1 using ssh...failed
byte-code: Host `server1' looks like a remote host, `ssh' can only use the local host
```

I am using tramp version 2.2.13-pre and emacs version 24.5.1. I have compiled emacs myself, in case it matters.

What can be going wrong? What could I try?

### EDIT

I am calling tramp like this:

```
C-x C-f /user@server1:filename
```

Comment: Can you tell how you call tramp ?

Answer (score 3):

Call `emacs -Q`. Likely, Tramp will work then. In this case, bisect your `.emacs` file and restart Emacs, until you find the package which causes the trouble.

One package which didn't cooperate well with Tramp was `projectile`. Disable it, when you are using it.

Comment: I have disabled el-get tramp (`2.2.13-pre`), and I get now `tramp 2.2.11-24.5` coming with emacs proper I am running emacs `24.5.1`. This version of tramp works.

Comment: Then this is a problem in either el-get or Tramp 2.2.13-pre. Reenable Tramp 2.2.13-pre, perform `(setq tramp-verbose 10)`, and rerun the test. There will be a Tramp debug buffer, which you might show. Since stackoverflow isn't good for analysing traces, you might send them to the Tramp mailing list `tramp-devel@gnu.org`.

Comment: What if it's a package installed with `(package-selected-packages)`, how do you bisect that? (`(custom-set-variables)` in my init file, with the scary comment about not messing up.)

Comment: Hmm, that might be problematic. I would go into `~/.emacs.d/elpa`, and try to deactivate one package after the other. By moving the respective directory somewhere else, changing directory's mode to 000, or something like this. After deactivating a package, restart Emacs, and check.

Comment: A `(setq load-path (append (list nil "~/lo/ca/tion") load-path))` in my init.el tripped Tramp. Found by bisecting. I don't understand why, but I'm happy, and you helped me.